# How do I send mail to gmail from my website email using php form script using mail function?

Tags: php, linux, function, email, gmail

I have a simple contact form below---

```
    <html>

   <head>
      <title>Sending HTML email using PHP</title>
   </head>

   <body>

      <?php
         $to = "contact@mydomain.com";
         $subject = "This is subject";

         $message = "<b>This is HTML message.</b>";
         $message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";

         $header = "From:jayaryaa@gmail.com \r\n";
         //$header .= "Cc:no-reply@skynetinfosolution.com \r\n";
         $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
         $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

         $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);

         if( $retval == true ) {
            echo "Message sent successfully...";
         }else {
            echo "Message could not be sent...";
         }
      ?>

   </body>
</html>
```

This script is working fine when I put my website email on place of $to , and when I enter my gmail id on place of FROM , my question is how can I send email to my gmail from my website email using mail  function ? ,I have tried by putting my gmail id in place of $to and my website email in place of From but it's not working , My website is a shared linux hosting .

Comment: Have you checked your spam/junk folder?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the PHPMailer [Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps). When you use the PHP mail function, you are sending email directly from your web server.Sending mail via SMTP is recommended as email is sent from the mail server rather than local server. This script lets you send messages via your Google’s Gmail server. Example below

```
<?php
/**
 * This example shows settings to use when sending via Google's Gmail servers.
 * This uses traditional id & password authentication - look at the gmail_xoauth.phps
 * example to see how to use XOAUTH2.
 * The IMAP section shows how to save this message to the 'Sent Mail' folder using IMAP commands.
 */
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;
//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), __DIR__);
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');
//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
    //Section 2: IMAP
    //Uncomment these to save your message in the 'Sent Mail' folder.
    #if (save_mail($mail)) {
    #    echo "Message saved!";
    #}
}
//Section 2: IMAP
//IMAP commands requires the PHP IMAP Extension, found at: https://php.net/manual/en/imap.setup.php
//Function to call which uses the PHP imap_*() functions to save messages: https://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php
//You can use imap_getmailboxes($imapStream, '/imap/ssl') to get a list of available folders or labels, this can
//be useful if you are trying to get this working on a non-Gmail IMAP server.
function save_mail($mail)
{
    //You can change 'Sent Mail' to any other folder or tag
    $path = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}[Gmail]/Sent Mail";
    //Tell your server to open an IMAP connection using the same username and password as you used for SMTP
    $imapStream = imap_open($path, $mail->Username, $mail->Password);
    $result = imap_append($imapStream, $path, $mail->getSentMIMEMessage());
    imap_close($imapStream);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I dont want to use php mailer , like my wesbite is skynet.com and email is info@skynet.com , how to send from info@skynet.com to my gmail id

Comment: I realize this now, honestly using PHPmailer is faster and easier. But in order for this to work I would try adding a fifth parameter to your mail() command:

`mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,"-f your@email.here");`

Comment: Also, double check the syntax and quotes for `mail()` [http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php]

Answer (score 0):

Isn't because your host prevent emails sending from another domain for spam issues ?

Eventually you can add a transfert rule from your Skynet to Gmail adress.